# <meta name="robots"> not working

Tags: html, meta, robots.txt

I have a page at:

https://www.luckycheckout.com/goto/282/cs/1?ct=1

which contains the following line of code in the head section:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

I also have "**Disallow: /goto**" in my "**robots.txt**" file.

However, despite this, Google Search Console is complaining that the page is:

**Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt**

As far as I can tell everything is both valid and correct and should not be indexed, can anybody explain what google is complaining about?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `Disallow` for this site on the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file:

> When Googlebot next crawls that page and see the tag or header, Googlebot will drop that page entirely from Google Search results, regardless of whether other sites link to it.
>
> **Important:** For the noindex directive to be effective, the page must not be blocked by a robots.txt file. If the page is blocked by a robots.txt file, the crawler will never see the noindex directive, and the page can still appear in search results, for example if other pages link to it.
> **source:** https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710

---

You can also remove a site you own from the Google index, using the Google Search Console. You can find more information on the [Google Webmaster documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419).

Comment: Sorry, but you missed the point of my question - the page has the noindex meta tag but it is still being indexed ... why?

Comment: OK thanks, the edited version sounds like it, I've tried it and I'll report back when google has crawled again

Comment: So...any update? ;P